# Get Text UIWebView PHP script

Tags: php, text, uiwebview, get

Basically my app has a UIwebView which loads a php script with input of user data. The script then uses printf(some info). This all works and it prints it right the UIWebView. Basically what I want to do is get that text (its all thats on the page) and save it as a string. Heres what I have tried so far.

```
NSString *str = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML"]; // also used document.documentElement.innerText and outerHTML and some others none seem to work
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

it returns nothing
How exactly should I do this. I assume its pretty simple I just need the correct text to put in evaulatingjavascriptfromstring. I just can't find out what I should put in.

Thnx,

Bryan

Answer (score 1):

You can try two things. First one is:

```
NSString *str = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

This will give you the HTML. Or if you don't want the HTML, just the actual text shown on the page then you can do:

```
NSString *str = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Hopefully this helps. Good luck.